# Drawing sprites in a grid formation

Tags: python, pygame, grid

I'm trying to draw sprites in a grid formation.  The sprites are in a 2D array, `self.components`.  The problem with this is that all of the sprites will be drawn where the last sprite in the grid should be.

```py
class Padding(Alignment):
    def __init__(self, spacing, components, columns):
        self.spacing = spacing
        self.components = components
        self.columns = columns

    def update_constraints(self, win):

        for row in range(0, self.columns):
            for column in range(0, len(self.components)//2):
                for i in self.components:
                    for j in i:
                        print(column * (win.s_width * self.spacing))
                        j.rect.x = column * (win.s_width * self.spacing)
                        j.rect.y = row * (win.s_height * self.spacing)
```

---

I'm using the padding class to draw the UI elements in a grid of slots. I'm adding a constraint to draw everything in `slots` in a grid, with a column size of 2.

```py
class Inventory(UILib.UIContainer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_alignment(UILib.UIConstraints.relative_width)
        self.add_alignment(UILib.UIConstraints.relative_height)
        self.slot_count = 10
        self.slots = []

        self.add_constraint(UILib.Padding(0.05, self.slots, 2))
```

With your implementation of `Padding`, this results in:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdmuY.png

Each `pg.rect` and the surface should be drawing with the exact same coordinates. (they are both contained in the same sub list so I don't know why this is happening). Also, since there are 10 slots and 2 rows than it should draw more like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kn3W.png

---

https://i.stack.imgur.com/McRrr.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a grid, only 2 nested loops a re necessary. Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to iterate through the nested list `self.components`:

```py
class Padding(Alignment):
    def __init__(self, spacing, components, columns):
        self.spacing = spacing
        self.components = components
        self.columns = columns

    def update_constraints(self, win):

        for column, rows in enumerate(self.components):
            for row, cell in enumerate(rows):

                print(column * (win.s_width * self.spacing))
                cell.rect.x = column * (win.s_width * self.spacing)
                cell.rect.y = row * (win.s_height * self.spacing)
```

Comment: My sprites are in a 2D array though.  The `self.components[i]` refers to a list that has the actual UI elements inside of it.  That is why I used several nested for loops.

Comment: @Hydra I don't know what I should do with this comment. What do you want to say? Do you mean that `self.components` is a nested list?

Comment: Yes, it's a nested list.  The UI components that actually have a `rect.x` value are in lists within `self.components`.  I'm not sure how to implement your solution because of this.

Comment: @Hydra I've changed the answer.

Comment: There is an issue that is kind of hard to explain through comments so I've edited my post.

Comment: @Hydra Do you mean that the rows and columns are swapped? I've changed the answer and swapped  `row` and `column`

Comment: I edited my post again to include the picture.  The problem is the surfaces are supposed to have the same x and y values of the `pg.rect`s.  Right now each surface is slightly below the `pg.rect`.  Also, the UI elements are not creating a new column.  It should be 2 columns.

Comment: The problem is that each UI element in the sublist are being displayed separately in their own column. Rather than being displayed together with the same x and y value.  Do you know how to fix this?